# Any idea how to change this mixing valve cartridge?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

When i move the tap left or right, back or forward the water does not change.
I removed the grub and took the handle off and can see this cartridge.

I am able to push it backwards and forwards but does nothing.

I think I need to replace this cartridge.

[image]

Comment: Including the make/model of the faucet will help immensely. If you don't know that, at least include a picture of the logo so someone might have a chance of identifying the brand. You can [edit] the info into your question, then take the [tour] to kill time while you're waiting for an answer.

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, I can't find any make, model, brand etc. Nothing except the tap.

Comment: There's no logo anywhere on the fixture handle? No identifying marks at all? At a minimum, I'd suggest removing the Phillips head screw in the middle to see if it pulls out, but I'm _NOT_ a faucet fixing expert. By the time ours have worn out, we've grown tired of the fixture itself and replaced the whole thing. (Plus PricePfister parts are unobtanium, yet we still seem to keep buying them...)

Comment: If you can't find identifiers, then you won't be able to get proper replacement parts.  Get a nice new assembly.

Comment: It's possible (likely, even) that a local plumbing supply house (not a big-box) would be able to identify the cartridge once it's been removed, @CarlWitthoft, but in general, I'd agree with you.

Comment: Looks like there's a hex nut two rings outside the blue.